# Export to CSV file after doing re.sub

Tags: regex, csv, export-to-csv

I wrote a code to do a substitution in a csv file. the code worked and I got the result:

```
import re
with open('c:\\users\\Mehrdad\\Desktop\\file.csv','r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
sub = re.sub(r"(\w+) (\d+) - (Present)" ,r"\1, \2, 2018", contents)
print (sub)
```

Now, I want to export the result to a CSV file but I tried many commands and still no answer for that! Does anyone know what command should I use to export the result?

Comment: You might want to use the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for operations such as this.

Comment: Thank you dawg. I will try to use it for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import re
with open('c:\\users\\Mehrdad\\Desktop\\file.csv','r') as f, open('output_file_name.csv', 'w') as out:
    contents = f.read()
    sub = re.sub(r"(\w+) (\d+) - (Present)" ,r"\1, \2, 2018", contents)
    out.write(sub)
print (sub)
```